# Can't log in to Stack Exchange

Tags: support, stack-exchange, login, user-accounts

Here is my issue:

I want to change the email address associated with my Stack Exchange account. When I log in at stackexchange.com I get the following message:

> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error
>     occurred while you were browsing our site.
>
> It's not you, it's us. This is our fault.
>
> Detailed information about this error has automatically been
>       recorded and we have been notified.

I can log in to other sites (such as Stack Overflow and Server Fault) with my Stack Exchange ID, but not to the Stack Exchange main page.

Is there a way for me to fix this or contact the Stack Exchange Team to check what's going on?

And yes, I have tried doing this from different web browsers and devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had two separate accounts - mostly using different email addresses, so they were never merged.

I was able to verify that they both belong to you (given some of your recent activity - I expect automated processes would have kicked off a merge, but I did one manually).

So, the accounts are now merged and you should be good to go.

Comment: That is phenomenal! Thanks alot for the help :)